# how to render child object array in react JS?

Tags: reactjs

I have children object array and I want to render it in template but it generate an error.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            data : {
                first:[
                    'name1',
                    'name2'
                ],
                second:[
                    'email1',
                    'email2'
                ]
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        const listItems = this.state.data.map((number,i) =>
          number.map((n,u)=>
            <li key={u} >{n}</li>
            )
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{listItems}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Error is :

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function.

Please help me to render this object into template and I am new to React JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't really `map` an object. You can get the keys of it by using `Object.keys(data)`, and then map it and get the value of data.

```
Object.keys(data).map(x=> {
  data[x].map((y,i)=> {
    <li key={u}>{y}</li>
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.data` is defined as an Object.[`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) only available on array.

Make `this.state.data` as an array.

```
this.state = {
            data : [
                first:[
                    'name1',
                    'name2'
                ],
                second:[
                    'email1',
                    'email2'
                ]
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using this.state.data1 in place of this.state.data.